# Does Eclipse use maven?

Tags: java, android, maven

I can't understand Gradle and Maven in Eclipse. I know that Gradle, Maven is a build automation system.

In Android Studio it uses Gradle and I can see the files to configure them.

But I can't find them in Eclipse? Does Eclipse use Maven or Gradle? Where can I confige it.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but have you even searched about the topic before asking here? Because typing "eclipse maven" inside google gave [this](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are Maven and Gradle plugins in Eclipse, which usually come preinstalled. You can generate Maven or Gradle projects in your workspace.

Comment: But what does Eclipse do by default. If I create a project, doesnt it uses maven or gradle for dependencies?

Comment: @Nataly no, not by default

Comment: If you create a Maven project, it uses Maven. You do not just create a project, but you choose a type of project.